# How to pass data to detail view after being selected in a uitableview cell

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, storyboard

I have a `UITableViewController` that has data populated from an NSMutableArray called userList. When specific user is selected, it goes to a detail view  but it wont display the data in  a `UITextview` and `UIImageview` in the `UIView`.(Detailview).I am Using Story board.This is my Sample code.

please give me any idea. Thanks in advance.

**Tableviewcontroller.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

{

[super viewDidLoad];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
//  tableData=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Alto",@"Estilo",@"Swift",@"Honda CRV",@"Ritz", nil];

thumbnails=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"car1.jpg",@"car2.jpg",@"car3.jpg",@"car4.jpg",@"car5.jpg", nil];

Car *car1=[Car new];
car1.carName=@"Alto";
car1.imageFile=@"Exotic_Car_-_Bugatti.jpg";
car1.carDetails=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Harsha    Mar05,2019",@"Registration   AP2911234",@"Model Year   2009",@"CarModel   Alto",@"Engine   StreamEngine",@"Petrol   Petrol",@"Exterior Color   Black",@"interior Color   Grey",@"Fuel Economy   1000",@"Insurance   Insurance",@"Life time tax   Free", nil];

Car *car2=[Car new];
car2.carName=@"Estilo";
car2.imageFile=@"images.jpg";
car2.carDetails=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Harsha    Mar05,2019",@"Registration   AP2911234",@"Model Year   2009",@"CarModel   Alto",@"Engine   StreamEngine",@"Petrol   Petrol",@"Exterior Color   Black",@"interior Color   Grey",@"Fuel Economy   1000",@"Insurance   Insurance",@"Life time tax   Free", nil];

Car *car3=[Car new];
car3.carName=@"Swift";
car3.imageFile=@"images1.jpg";
car3.carDetails=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Harsha    Mar05,2019",@"Registration   AP2911234",@"Model Year   2009",@"CarModel   Alto",@"Engine   StreamEngine",@"Petrol   Petrol",@"Exterior Color   Black",@"interior Color   Grey",@"Fuel Economy   1000",@"Insurance   Insurance",@"Life time tax   Free", nil];

Car *car4=[Car new];
car4.carName=@"Honda CRV";
car4.imageFile=@"index.jpg";
car4.carDetails=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Harsha    Mar05,2019",@"Registration   AP2911234",@"Model Year   2009",@"CarModel   Alto",@"Engine   StreamEngine",@"Petrol   Petrol",@"Exterior Color   Black",@"interior Color   Grey",@"Fuel Economy   1000",@"Insurance   Insurance",@"Life time tax   Free", nil];

Car *car5=[Car new];
car5.carName=@"Ritz";
car5.imageFile=@"Sport_Super_car.jpg";
car5.carDetails=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Harsha    Mar05,2019",@"Registration   AP2911234",@"Model Year   2009",@"CarModel   Alto",@"Engine   StreamEngine",@"Petrol   Petrol",@"Exterior Color   Black",@"interior Color   Grey",@"Fuel Economy   1000",@"Insurance   Insurance",@"Life time tax   Free", nil];

tableData=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:car1,car2,car3,car4,car5, nil];


}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

return [tableData count];

}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

 static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier=@"CarCell";

UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) 
{

cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

 }


Car *car = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = car.carName;
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

return 78;

}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 

{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showcardetails"]) 

{

 NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];


CarDetailviewViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

destViewController.car = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 // Hide bottom tab bar in the detail view
destViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;


}

}
```

**CarDetailviewcontroller.m**

```
@synthesize carPhoto;
@synthesize cardetailsTextView;
@synthesize car;

- (void)viewDidLoad

{

[super viewDidLoad];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
self.title = car.carName;
self.carPhoto.image = [UIImage imageNamed:car.imageFile];

NSMutableString *ingredientText = [NSMutableString string];

for (NSString* ingredient in car.carDetails) 
{

[ingredientText appendFormat:@"%@\n", ingredient];

}

self.cardetailsTextView.text = ingredientText;

}
```

Comment: In your **Car.m** `viewDidLoad` have you tried `NSLog(@"car %@",car);` ?

Comment: in my car.m i declared only variables.

Answer (score 1):

In your `CarDetailviewcontroller.m` you have to alloc your variable type `car`

If `car` is `string` than you do somthing like that

```
 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization
           car = [[NSString all]init];
        }
        return self;
    }
```

i hope after that your code is work fine

Answer (score 0):

If you're using storyboards there's an excellent way to do it: Use segues.

1. In the storyboard, crtl-drag from the tableview cell to the destination view controller.
2. select the circle in the connecting line that forms the segue and in the property editor go to the fourth section and give the segue a name in the identifier field, something like 'pushToDetail'.
3. In the code of the starting table view controller add a method called...

   `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender`
4. In this method you can use the segue variable it receives to reference the destination view controller and send it some data. For example:

   `CarDetailViewController *carDetailVC = segue.destinationViewController;`

then you can send it data, so if it has an array property you could...

`[carDetailVC setPhoto:[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];`

1. So the last question is how do you trigger the segue? That's the easiest bit... In your table view controller, make sure you implement the method:

   `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

and in that method tell the segue to happen like so:

`[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushToDetail" sender:self];`

See that the identifier is the one you specified in the storyboard in step 2.

It's a great way to send data between view controllers.
There's proper documentation on the Apple Developer site in the View Controller Programming Guide for iOS.

Comment: hi @MightyLeader I AM editing like this.But getting errors.plz give me any idea.- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    CarDetailviewViewController *carDetailVC = segue.destinationViewController;
    [carDetailVC setPhoto:[thumbnails objectAtIndex:_indexPath.row]];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushToDetail" sender:self];
}

Comment: looks like you're calling performSegueWithIDentifier in the wrong place. You call it in the method that responds to the cell selection.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Download the complete source code [here](https://docs.google.com/a/witinnovation.com/file/d/0B38jUuz50boOTVlFcWxDWTh3QzA/edit)

Create a Property in your detailView

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;
```

then in your Tableviewcontroller class replace this

```
 [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];];
```

In Place of

```
destViewController.car = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Happy coding..

Comment: i am trying to above code.But not display data in detailview controller

Comment: Hi Murthy, This is very simple to do i will recomend you to simply open one new Master-Detail Application template with storyboard clicked and check the code there.

Comment: hi i edited the above code in MasterDetailAPplication.But the table data does not displayed.Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

As the detailviewcontroller is already initialized it won´t show any change, add all the changes in a public method and call it after you make the:

```
destViewController.car = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```